# Firestore Batch Delete

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, angular6

i am trying to delete a document and sub collection of documents in a collection using batch write.here is my code;

```
const batch = this.afs.firestore.batch();
  const ref = this.afs.firestore.collection(`customers`).doc(`${id}`);
  const subCollectionDocs = await this.afs.firestore.collection(`customers/${id}/address`).get();
  if (!subCollectionDocs.empty) {
     subCollectionDocs.forEach(subDocs => {
      const subDocRef = this.afs.firestore.collection(`customers/${id}/address`).doc(`${subDocs.id}`);
      batch.delete(subDocRef);
    })
  }
  batch.delete(ref);
  return batch.commit();
```

as of my code 'ref' is pointing towards the root collection documents and 'subDocRef' pointing towards the sub-collection documents;

But when i changing 'ref' to an invalid document reference manullay it still deletes the subCollection Documents, even they are in a single batch.? Can somebody explain it.?